# Output de-duplication with aggregated calculation checks

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

We have a dataset where users (distinct) have facilities (multiple) which contain accounts (multiple) which have holdings (multiple).

I came across duplication cases where for example:
`user_ID='A'` has `facility_ID='1'` with `account_ID in ('A','B)` and `facility_ID='2'` with `account_ID in ('C','D)`, where the `count(accounts)`, `sum(holdings amount)` and every `holdings_amount` values for both facilities is **identical**.

```
user_id facility_id facility_name account_id holdings_amount
A       1           Fidelity      A           100
A       1           Fidelity      A           200
A       1           Fidelity      B           300
A       1           Fidelity      B           400
A       2           Fidelity      C           200
A       2           Fidelity      C           100
A       2           Fidelity      D           400
A       2           Fidelity      D           300
A       3           Fidelity      E           100
A       3           Fidelity      E           200
A       3           Fidelity      F           700
A       4           Fidelity      G           200
A       4           Fidelity      G           100
A       4           Fidelity      H           400
A       4           Fidelity      H           300
```

**SQL Fiddle with appropriate data:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/697f6/1

At the `user` level, what I would like is to do the following:

1. **IF** `count(facilities) >1` (note that can be >2)
2. AND `facility_name` = `facility_name`
3. AND `count(accounts)` from one `facility` = `count(accounts)` of another
4. AND `count(holdings_amount)` from one `account` = `count(holdings_amount)` of another
5. AND `sum(holdings_amount)` from one `account` = `sum(holdings_amount)` of another
6. AND every `holdings amount` value from one `account` equals every `holdings amount` value of another (in any order)

**THEN** exclude the counts for the duplicated `facility` (ie. the `accounts` linked to it).

So the expected output would be:

```
user_id facility_id facility_name account_id holdings_amount
A       1           Fidelity      A           100
A       1           Fidelity      A           200
A       1           Fidelity      B           300
A       1           Fidelity      B           400
A       3           Fidelity      E           100
A       3           Fidelity      E           200
A       3           Fidelity      F           700
A       4           Fidelity      G           200
A       4           Fidelity      G           100
A       4           Fidelity      H           400
A       4           Fidelity      H           300
```

Since facility 2 violates all 6 points, facility 3 doesnt violate point 4, and facility 4 doesnt violate point 6.

Please let me know if anything is unclear or if I can provide more detail. Thanks!

Comment: I'd look into a full outer join to match up the holdings amounts.

Comment: @shawnt00 I can't see how to incorporate it here, but would love to find a solution, this is quite overstated and causing issues on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I had in mind although it doesn't appear to return results in your fiddle.

```
select
    a2.id,
    count(h1.id), count(h2.id), count(distinct a1.id), count(distinct a2.id)
from
    (
        facilities f1
        inner join accounts a1 on a1.facility_id = f1.id
        inner join holdings h1 on h1.acc_id = a1.id
    )
    full outer join
    (
        facilities f2
        inner join accounts a2 on a2.facility_id = f2.id
        inner join holdings h2 on h2.acc_id = a2.id)
    on      f2.id <> f1.id
        and a2.id > a1.id
        and f2.facility_name = f1.facility_name
        and h2.holdings_amount = h1.holdings_amount
group by a2.id
having
        count(h1.id) = count(h2.id)
    and count(distinct a1.id) = count(distinct a2.id)
    and sum(h1.holdings_amount) = sum(h2.holdings_amount)
    and count(h1.id) = count(*) and count(h2.id) = count(*);
```

Coming back to it I realize that you do have constraints on multiple levels that wouldn't be handled by this. This might help you get on the right track but I can think of a few problems up in there.

Comment: actually fixing this to run DID identify the incorrect accounts that should be removed, so running my original query with account not in account from this query does fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
with f_agg as (
    select f.user_id, f.id, f.facility_name,
        count(distinct a.id)  as a_cnt,
        count(distinct h.id) as h_cnt,
        sum(h.holdings_amount) as h_tot,
        sum(cast(h.id as int)) as h_chk
    from
        facilities f
        inner join accounts a on a.facility_id = f.id
        inner join holdings h on h.acc_id = a.id
    group by f.user_id, f.id, f.facility_name
), potential as (
    select fa1.id as id1, fa2.id as id2
    from f_agg as fa1 cross join f_agg as fa2
    where fa2.id > fa1.id
            and fa2.user_id = fa1.user_id
            and fa2.facility_name = fa1.facility_name
            and fa2.a_cnt = fa1.a_cnt
            and fa2.h_cnt = fa1.h_cnt
            and fa2.h_tot = fa1.h_tot
),
matches as (
    select coalesce(p1.id1, p2.id1) as id1, coalesce(p1.id2, p2.id2) as id2
    from
        (
        potential p1
        inner join f_agg fa1 on fa1.id = p1.id1
        inner join accounts a1 on a1.facility_id = fa1.id
        inner join
            (
            select *, row_number() over (partition by acc_id order by id) as rn
            from holdings
            ) h1 on h1.acc_id = a1.id
        )
        full outer join
        (
        potential p2
        inner join f_agg fa2 on fa2.id = p2.id2
        inner join accounts a2 on a2.facility_id = fa2.id  
        inner join 
            (
            select *, row_number() over (partition by acc_id order by id) as rn
            from holdings
            ) h2 on h2.acc_id = a2.id
        )
        on      p2.id1 = p1.id1 and p2.id2 = p1.id2
            and h2.rn = h1.rn and h2.holdings_amount = h1.holdings_amount
    group by coalesce(p1.id1, p2.id1), coalesce(p1.id2, p2.id2)
    having   count(h1.id) = count(*)
         and count(h2.id) = count(*)
         and sum(cast(h1.id as int)) = min(fa1.h_chk)
         and sum(cast(h2.id as int)) = min(fa2.h_chk)
)
select * from matches;
```

Leaving this here in case I come back to play more: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/697f6/120

Comment: You had it right the first time around! This query excludes looking that every position is the same, so institution 4 is incorrectly excluded.